# Issue caching images with custom collection view cell using KingFisher

Tags: swift, caching, uicollectionview, kingfisher

I'm using Kingfisher to cache an image that is stored in Firebase. I'm retrieving the image with a url call to Firebase, then attempting to cache that image for re-use. The below logic in `configureCell(with video:Video)` was previously in `cellForItemAt` and the image caching worked just fine. However, after moving this logic to the custom cell and calling this function from `cellForItemAt`, the images aren't being retrieved through the cache. Every image is downloaded, then re-downloaded if it re-appears in the collection view. My code is below. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
class ProminentVideoCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!

func configureCell(with video:Video) {
    self.timeLabel.text = video.date?.getElapsedInterval()
    let thumbnailImageView = UIImageView()
    ImageCache.default.retrieveImage(forKey: video.thumbnailurl!, options: nil) {
        image, cacheType in
        if let image = image {
            //Video thumbnail exists in cache--set it
            thumbnailImageView.image = image
            self.backgroundView = thumbnailImageView
            print("Get image \(image), cacheType: \(cacheType).")

        } else {
            //Video thumbnail does NOT exist in cache, download it
            video.downloadThumbnailFromStorage(with: { (url) in
                let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: url, cacheKey: video.thumbnailurl!)
                let processor = BlurImageProcessor(blurRadius: 40.0) >> RoundCornerImageProcessor(cornerRadius: 20)

                thumbnailImageView.kf.setImage(with: resource, options: [.processor(processor)])
                self.backgroundView = thumbnailImageView
            })


        }
    }
}
```

In my View Controller:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let currentVideo = self.selectedVideosArray.object(at: indexPath.row) as! Video
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ProminentVideoCollectionViewCell
        cell.configureCell(with: currentVideo)
        return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the below code to ensure the caching mechanism worked. Not entirely sure why the `thumbnailImageView.kf.setImage` wasn't caching the images, but adding the below code did the trick.

```
//Video thumbnail does NOT exist in cache, download it
            video.downloadThumbnailFromStorage(with: { (url) in
                let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: url, cacheKey: video.thumbnailurl!)
                let processor = BlurImageProcessor(blurRadius: 40.0) >> RoundCornerImageProcessor(cornerRadius: 20)

                thumbnailImageView.kf.setImage(with: resource, options: [.processor(processor)], completionHandler: { (image, error, cacheType, url) in
                    ImageCache.default.store(image!, forKey: video.thumbnailurl!)
                    self.backgroundView = thumbnailImageView
                })
            })
```